# Rotate writeable bitmap without creating a new bitmap

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap

Ok so here's how this works:

1. camera sends me an image as a writeable bitmap
    client.WhenMasterFrameCaptured().ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current).Subscribe(frame => UpdateMasterCameraPreview(frame));
2. I set that pointer to an image source(wpf Image control) in the method that this is subscribed to

   ```
           if (cameraOneBitmap != null)
           {
               frame.Image.CopyTo(cameraOneBitmap);

           }

           else
           {
               cameraOneBitmap = frame.Image.ToWriteableBitmap();
           }

           cameraOneBitmap.Lock();
           cameraOneBitmap.AddDirtyRect(new Int32Rect(0, 0, cameraOneBitmap.PixelWidth, cameraOneBitmap.PixelHeight));
           cameraOneBitmap.Unlock();

           cameraOneImage.Source = cameraOneBitmap;
   ```

The Problem: The method feeds me a bitmap that isn't the correct angle and i have no way of changing that. I must rotate it. I'm currently using a render transform in xaml. the problem is it shapes the image all weird in certain window sizes it hangs over the grid into the bottom of the window so i don't want to use that. I've tried using writeablebitmapex library but it creates a new bitmap and that gives me an out of memory exception in about 10 seconds... Is there a way to rotate this bitmap with out have to make a new one every time? Somehow the render transform does it without giving me problems. I was doing this to set the source but it still gives me an exception because it makes a new one.

```
public static RenderTargetBitmap RotateImage(double angle, WriteableBitmap sourceBitmap)
{
    TransformedBitmap tb = new TransformedBitmap(sourceBitmap, new RotateTransform(angle));
    DrawingVisual drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
    DrawingContext drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen();
    drawingContext.DrawImage(tb, new Rect(0, 0, tb.PixelWidth, tb.PixelHeight));

    //drawingContext.PushTransform(new RotateTransform(270, .5, .5));
    drawingContext.Close();

    System.Windows.Media.Imaging.RenderTargetBitmap bmp = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.RenderTargetBitmap(tb.PixelWidth, tb.PixelHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
    bmp.Render(drawingVisual);


    return bmp;
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Have you tried rotating the Image control?

Comment: Yes that's the render transform in xaml

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you've moved on but for posterity the solution is to use **LayoutTransform** instead of **RenderTransform**.

When you use RenderTransform, all the layout calculations are performed with you element unrotated.  Then the RenderTransform is applied.

The LayoutTransform performs the the rotation and then calculates the layout.